# Rails new command fails if -m template is applied: "NoMethodError: private method `open' called for URI:Module"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, open-uri, thor

I have been bumping into this issue and could not find a way to fix it.

When I am creating new rails apps *using templates*, the generator fails on `private method 'open' called for URI:Module (NoMethodError)`

Either way `rails new app_name -m any_template_url` or `bin/rails app:template LOCATION=http://example.com/template.rb` would return the same failure.

This is the terminal print out:

```
/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/thor-1.2.1/lib/thor/actions.rb:226:in `apply': private method `open' called for URI:Module (NoMethodError)

from /.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:170:in `apply_rails_template'

from (eval):1:in `apply_rails_template'
```

for which I understand the issue take place [when we try to open the path to the file to execute](https://github.com/rails/thor/blob/main/lib/thor/actions.rb#L226) and
[when rails tries to apply the template](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/470e6bdac97249ca3406c635f611aa8f7df8b222/railties/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb#L166)

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Rails 5.2 is recommended to use ruby 2.5. Update your ruby ​​version ​​and try again.

Reference: https://www.fastruby.io/blog/ruby/rails/versions/compatibility-table.html

Comment: Note to reviewers: this is *not* a link-only question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer